# Software restore on iBook G4 A1134

Tags: powerpc, ibook

I recently bought an iBook and OS 10.3.3 iBook recovery discs. I have inserted the disc to restore the iBook but after booting with the disc inserted the screen in just black. There has been no dialogue to, for example, start the system restore. I have no experience with apple products of this age. Is this the usual experience? Is something going wrong? It has been like this for probably half an hour at least. I inserted the disc while logged in and started the Install OS X programme which restarted the computer. I had previously inserted the disc and help the C key to start it but encountered the same thing.

Comment: Troubleshooting OS installs are challenging. Can you restart the install and when it starts, press Command L and Command 3? Then you will have error log visible to take a picture if it hangs.

Answer (score 3):

The A1134 model is the 2005 14 inch iBook. The original supplied OS was 10.4.2 (Tiger), so OS 10.3 won't work on it.

However, I'd also want to make sure that the screen actually works before buying a Tiger installer disk.

Comment: Is there any way to get 10.3 working? It would be very annoying to have wasted money on the install discs. The screen does work and currently runs leopard but I need to downgrade to get some software working/

Comment: @math 10.3.3 does not have the hardware drivers for computers from the future. Given the similarity with the previous model, it might be possible to hack the hardware check, and it might work.

Comment: There's a file on the installer disk that you'll need to edit, and then burn a copy of the installer with the modified file. There should be lots of internet pages describing how to get various MacOS versions running on non-supported hardware, and the principle should be the same.

Comment: What's the software, btw? Could you run it in Sheepshaver (Classic Mac emulator), on a newer Mac?

Comment: The software is a rather obscure mathematical software. I tried to run it in Leopard but it said something like it needed the classic environment so I tried to downgrade. I tried to get an emulator working on my Windows machine but it seemed too complicated. A related question would be is there a way around the classic environment on 10.5? Would an emulator work on this?